# Loop with open() for sys.stdin

Tags: python

I was testing the following code for 2 files filenameC and filenameA and it works fine:

```
with  open(locationA + filenameC,'r') as fileC, open(locationA + filenameA,'r') as fileA:
```

Now I would like to use this code on AWS with more than 1 file for filenameC and filenameA.
I was thinking about using sys.stdin but I am a beginer on Python and I cannot figure out how to use it.
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking to read from stdin? If so you don't have to open it like a normal file as it is already open. You can simply use it as it if were an open file. i.e. you can do `lines = sys.stdin.readlines()` if that's what you're asking. However if you continue to read from stdin you will need to put some form of check/flush as it will loop forever.

Comment: Look into the [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) module: it allows getting input from stdin or a set of files.